# Correct SQL syntax to get data from table1 where ids in table2 don't exists

Tags: sql, database

I have this data in `table1`

```
| id_modul | name_modul |
==========================
| 1         | Modul 1    |
| 2         | Modul 2    |
| 3         | Modul 3    |
| 4         | Modul 4    |
| 5         | Modul 5    |
==========================
```

and data `table2`

```
| id_akses  | id_modul   |
==========================
| 1         | 3          |
| 2         | 4          |
==========================
```

This is the SQL   syntax I tried:

```
SELECT table1.name_modul
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id_modul = table2.id_modul
```

i get this result :

```
Modul 1
Modul 2
Modul 3
Modul 4
Modul 5
```

But, I am expecting this result :

```
Modul 1
Modul 2
Modul 5
```

How do I correct my SQL query to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.name_modul
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id_modul = table2.id_modul
WHERE table2.id_modul IS NULL
```

Result:

```
NAME_MODUL
Modul 1
Modul 2
Modul 5
```

Result in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4990a/2).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.name_modul
FROM table1
Where table1.id_modul not in (select id_modul from table2 where table2.id_modul = table1.id_modul)
```

Comment: IMO this will be inefficient. You are making two queries to fetch and match the absence of `id_modul`.